# Create a for list from a json website request in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, payload

I want to iterate through every other column of my xlsx file which contains a company name in each row. The code works if I enter a company name, e.g., in the line "name": 'Stibahlife GmbH' and the code extracts the legal form.

However, when implementing a for loop, the code does yield the error below, and does not print all respective legal forms. How to fix this?

```
import json
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd

results_folder = r'C:\Users\...'
results_file = os.path.join(results_folder, 'Companies.xlsx')
results_df = pd.read_excel(results_file, header=None)

# read every second column, starting with column B in the xlsx file
results = results_df[results_df.columns[1::2]]

# legal form
for name in results:
    legal_forms_url = "https://www.zefix.ch/ZefixREST/api/v1/legalForm.json"
    search_api = "https://www.zefix.ch/ZefixREST/api/v1/firm/search.json"

    legal_forms = {f["id"]: f for f in requests.get(legal_forms_url).json()}
    payload = {
        "languageKey": "en",
        "maxEntries": 30,
        "name": name,
        "offset": 0,
        "searchType": "exact",
    }

    data = requests.post(search_api, json=payload).json()
    print(legal_forms[data["list"][0]["legalFormId"]]["name"]["en"])
```

This is the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\11_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(legal_forms[data["list"][0]["legalFormId"]]["name"]["en"])
                      ~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'list'
```

Comment: It would seem the request probably failed. You should print the value of `data` to check what you are getting.

Comment: @Nick I am getting the error {'error': {'code': 'API.ERROR.GENERAL', 'title': 'API.ERROR.GENERAL', 'message': None, 'suggestion': 'API.HINT.PAGE.RELOAD', 'internal_message': None}}. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well it looks like the request indeed did fail. Since I don't know the API you're calling, it's hard to offer advice as to where to go from here. You might want to loop over `data = requests.post(search_api, json=payload).json()` until you get a result that does not contain `error` or you reach a number of tries (e.g. 3).